# Winforms toolbar of buttons wrapping . 

Tags: c#, winforms, toolbar, button

I am dynamically added a bunch of buttons to a toolbar.  I want the ability to programatically make it wrap onto a second row if the number of buttons exceeds the horizontal space in the current form.  I dont want users to have to click the dropdown button to view more buttons as i need to ensure that all buttons are viewable always.

are there any suggestions for how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need just four lines. First, disable docking:

```
Me.ToolStrip1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.None
```

Then turn off auto-sizing:

```
Me.ToolStrip1.AutoSize = False
```

Now set the layout to "Flow"

```
Me.ToolStrip1.LayoutStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripLayoutStyle.Flow
```

Then then change the size to double the height of a normal ToolStrip, or whatever you want.

```
Me.ToolStrip1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(300, 50)
```

Comment: Correct answer for ToolStrip (and maybe he means that) but the Q is tagged ToolBar